# Can a puppy chew through a 10-gauge power extension cable?

Tags: safety

I have multiple 10-gauge, heavy-duty extension cords in my house powering industrial grade computers for cryptocurrency mining- could a puppy chew through this strength of cable?  The only reason why I ask is because there are products like [CritterCords](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000EH2I5O) marketed for pet-owners to protect pets from chewing through standard electrical cords.  It would seem like a 10-gauge power cable would afford the same protection claimed by a CritterCord.  Thanks!

Comment: Given enough time and boredom, a puppy can claw and chew its way through a wooden door. A cable is no big challange. You need to keep in mind that the dog doesn't even have to chew the cable in two. Just piercing through the insulation and slobbering into the cable is enough to cause a short.

Comment: If you have a puppy, keep it a) supervised at all times and b) offer enough mental stimulation and physical exercise and c) remove dangerous objects from their reach. Everything else starts after that.

Comment: @Elmy: causing a short (wire-to-wire) is the happiest thing that can happen. The desirable thing, actually, thinking that OP considers electricity a hack-able joke.

Comment: And looking at some customer reviews, the scent-based deterrent in your question is also not working in all cases.

Comment: @Stephie, Agreed.  I’ve taken precautions- instead, I’m keeping secluded on one side of the house that is completely wire-free.  Thank you for all of your constructive answers and commentary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes a puppy can chew through a power cable and so can most other pets and critters.

The only safe thing to do is to put the cable in an area where your pet are unable to reach it,or to keep your pet away from the danger area.

The main reason for different products to work keeping pets away is because they have chemicals in them that has a unpleasant taste or smell like the crittercord has,it is not because the products can withstand chewing from sharp teeth.

Comment: What about adding Keep Off spray to the 10-gauge cables- would that afford comparable protection to something like a CritterCord?

Comment: The problem with all deterrents is that they sometimes really “work” only after the first taste - which can be too late for a curious puppy. And when they are teething, they will gnaw on *everything*, trying to soothe the discomfort.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that has teeth, and enough determination and patience, can (and will) chew through anything.

The only safe way is to place the cables wherever the place of the cables is. Anyway far enough and well protected from living beings.

About chemicals with repelling effect: on the long run, they might be dangerous for the health of your dog, and maybe for other living beings in the house too.

Rather than "hack and hope", please do the right thing and hide those cables.

What will happen if the dog is still connected to the electrical wire (alive or not-any-more - the dog, I mean) and someone will jump and grab the dog, trying to save it?

---

Bottom line: there is no hack for proper safety. Please do the right thing and do not mingle with the "experts" for the internet. They will not return anyone's life back.

Answer (score 0):

Make no mistake...puppies can chew through almost anything. You essentially have to puppy proof a home the way you'd baby proof a home. They explore the world with their mouths and if they're bored they'll find something to chew on! If you're not sure about something then the best bet is to get it out of reach of your puppy.

Comment: Maybe you are a bit extreme with "puppies can chew through *almost anything*" :D But not *very* wrong wither, on the other hand...